# How to get Recent Test Case Results by Test Case ID using TFS REST API

Tags: rest, azure, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-analysis

Is there a way to get the **recent test results** of test case by Test Case ID utilizing TFS REST API (Azure DevOps Services REST API).

Required field is the **Outcome** of test case, **Duration**, **Date**, **Configuration** and **Run By**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this api to get a specific test case in a test suite with test case id.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases/{testCaseIds}?api-version=5.0
```

for getting test result please refer below api

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

for further information, you can refer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20case%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, already tried it. But I need some to get a list of recent test results by only test case ID. If you know the way to do it, please share :)

Comment: Basically you need list of run history of a particular test case. Is this what you need? I have not used this API but this seems relevant for you case : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20history/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0